# How to get all list items using ref?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I know how to get parent `ul` by just doing `this.$refs.listOfItems` but not sure how to get all the `li`s in `ul` list.

I also know the JS way of doing it `document.getElementById("listOfItems").getElementsByTagName("li");` but as mentioned above I am looking for helpers offered by Vue.js like `this.$refs`

```
<template>
  <ul id="listOfItems" ref="listOfItems">
    <li v-for="item in items">{{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted: {
      let ul = this.$refs.listOfItems
      let lis =  // HOW TO GET ALL LIs using `this.$refs.listOfItems`
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to put the `v-for` on the `<li>` instead of the `<ul>`. If you put a `ref` on an element that is repeated with `v-for`, then it will be an array of the items.

```vue
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in items" ref="items">{{ item.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

```js
this.$refs.items[0];  // The first <li>
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the wrong placement of `v-for` but that was added there by mistake, you got first `li` but how to get all `li`s that we usually do in JS this way?  `document.getElementById("listOfItems").getElementsByTagName("li")`

Comment: `this.$refs.items` *is* all the items – it's an array.

Comment: ah! got it, thanks. The other way I tried and worked which is not as good as yours :) is: `this.$refs.listOfItems.getElementsByTagName('li')`